# mysql multiple word search

Tags: php, mysql, search

i have a mysql table and a search form
i am filtering the table acc to the given conditions 
but my problem is i want to search multiple words from string field 
could you please help me how to do this :
i mean i want to allow it to be written multiple words in the string and want them to be searched by "AND"

```
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (customername LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR definition LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}
if ($_REQUEST["customername"]<>'') {
    $search_customername = " AND customername='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["customername"])."'";   
}

if ($_REQUEST["date"]<>'' and ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'' or $_REQUEST["customername"]<>'') ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * from ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE date = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["date"])."' ".$search_string.$search_customername;
} else
if ($_REQUEST["date"]<>'' and ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'' or $_REQUEST["customername"]<>'' ) ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * from ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE date = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["date"])."' ".$search_string.$search_customername;
} else

if ($_REQUEST["date"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["string"]=='' and $_REQUEST["customername"]=='') {
    $sql = "SELECT * from ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE date = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["date"])."' ";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_customername;
}
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860046#12860046